# Как в Java заменить каждые 5 неизвестных букв на слово?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток!

Есть задача заменить каждые 5 букв в предложении на слово или цифры например "12345", чтобы получилось примерно так: "Приветствую (12345123451)".

Помогите, пожалуйста, знатоки!

Comment: @arkanium, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @arkanium, уточните вопрос, а то ничего не понятно из примера. А также назначение этого кода.